# Print Preview issues after running large amount of VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook in which almost everything is automated.  It opens other workbooks, copies data from them, closes them and then loops through the data several times to generate reports that we print and use.  Almost every time after running all the VBA and then trying to print, print preview gets stuck either finding the printer or loading page sizes as seen in the picture.  Closing Excel and reopening the document restores print preview to normal functionality.  The only thing related to printing that the VBA does is change the print area.  I have not had this issue with any other documents that run VBA.  Is this just a bug or possibly something in the code?

[image: Issue]

This is the code that causes print preview to fail to load in some way.  If I skip this section then it works as intended...  I would like to have this code function in some way as it's still needed.

```
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

    For i = LBound(sArray) To UBound(sArray) 'Loops through array, copies available data from last report
        ShtName = sArray(i, 0)
        On Error Resume Next
            wb1.Sheets(ShtName).Activate
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                wb1.Sheets(ShtName).Activate
                Columns("A:U").Copy
                wb2.Sheets(ShtName).Activate
                Columns("BE:BV").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "BE").End(xlUp).Row
                Range("BA2:BC2").Select
                Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, "BA"), Cells(lastrow, "BC")), Type:=xlFillDefault
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        DoEvents

    Next i

    wb1.Close False

    Sheet2.Activate
```

I've tried commenting out "On Error Resume Next", "On Error Goto 0", "If...", "End If", and "DoEvents".  Print Preview still fails with those removed and just doing the copy and paste from the previous sheet.

Comment: You need to provide some additional information if you're looking for a solution. What's the code? What happens if you don't run the print area part of the code? Does it happen on every machine? What about different versions of excel?

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what is going on?  There may be an issue with the opening or losing of the workbooks.  You can try setting the activePrinter or the the paperSize something like this  `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Name").PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal`

Comment: Perhaps you can check the Names collection at both workbook and worksheet level _after_ you've run the VBA. If you find there are multiple Print_Area names or any other weird Name entries then that might be your culprit. The giveaway is that the problem is eliminated by restarting Excel which suggests that Names from the workbooks you iterate through in the process are polluting your Names collection in the main workbook that has the Print Preview problem.

Comment: As you found the piece of code causing the trouble, why don't you try commenting just parts of it to see which code line is giving the headache?

Comment: The line causing the issue is this `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, "BA"), Cells(lastrow, "BC")), Type:=xlFillDefault`

Comment: Ok the main culprit here seems to be this code `=SUMIFS(BA:BA,B:B,BF2,D:D,BH2)` that is filled in column BC.  Print preview works fine if that is set to 0.  The odd thing is that the formula doesn't remain all the way to end, the last sub that runs copies everything and pastes values to remove the formula so the values don't change when working with the data.

Comment: Ok, it seems any formula put into column "BC" prevents Print Preview from working and causes me to get the message "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" when I close the workbook.  I've tried moving that formula to "BB", deleting all further references to the formula in the code and nothing seems to work.  I've also tried rebuilding the workbook as new.

Even worse, if I step through each sub then Print Preview works fine but if I just run it without breaks then it doesn't.  Think it's time to give up on this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that removing all instances of `DoEvents` has fixed the issue...

Print Preview works correctly and Excel does not crash when exiting the workbook anymore.

Comment: Alas you have discovered horrors of doevents. I am not saying it 100% evil but in most cases it creates more problems than it solves. Upvote for knowing doevents

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for some type of refresh action that can re-sync the preview display with the data on the sheet. You might want to try this at the end:

```
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False  
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

If that doesn't work, see if manually saving fixes the issue. You can try calling `Application.Save` at the end.

Comment: I will give the calculation settings a try Monday.  I know this issue happens before saving and after using save as.  The document will still print if you click print even with the display/paper size failing.

Comment: Adding this to each sheet did not fix it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

"Print preview occurs automatically when you choose File --> Print. Another option is to use the Page Layout view (the icon on the right side of the status bar). To get the old-style print preview, you need to use VBA. The following statement displays a print preview of the active sheet: `ActiveSheet.PrintPreview` "

Quoted from ***Microsoft Excel 2013 Power Programming with VBA*** by John Walkenbach, pages 956-957.

That being said, I tested your issue above by recording a relatively complex macro that creates a new sheet, performs 25 automatic actions, and shows a print preview, then closes the print preview when I click OK on a MsgBox. I iterated the program to do this 1000 times. I never had an issue with the PrintPreview.

Comment: I will look into adding the print preview VBA.  Right now the sheets that are usually printed are generated from a list so I use a template that is copied.  It creates on average 1-12 sheets from the list, copies data from an older workbook, loops through around 3,000 rows to populate the created sheets then loops through around 40,000 rows to add more information to the sheets.  It would probably benefit from a rewrite now that the feature creep has ended but I don't see myself having the time for that...

Comment: Agreed @tjb1, that time is a rare resource. What I would do in your situation is not attempt a whole rewrite, but start with a testable copy of the original code saved to your desktop (vice a network server or something). Then, try simple changes as you have time. For example, the VBA code `ActiveSheet.PrintPreview` relies on an older, less memory intensive Print Preview, which may be enough to fix the glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of a shot in the dark, but I tried cleaning up your code a little bit. See if that has any affect at all.

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim isWS As Boolean

On Error GoTo sub_err

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

For i = LBound(sArray) To UBound(sArray) 'Loops through array, copies available data from last report
    ShtName = sArray(i, 0)
    isWS = True
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(ShtName)

    If isWS Then
        Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(ShtName)

        ws1.Columns("A:U").Copy
        ws2.Columns("BE:BV").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "BE").End(xlUp).Row
        ws2.Range("BA2:BC2").AutoFill Destination:=ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, "BA"), ws2.Cells(lastrow, "BC")), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End If
    DoEvents
Next i

wb1.Close False

ws2.Activate

sub_exit:
Exit Sub

sub_err:
If Err.Number = 9 Then
    isWS = False
    Resume Next
Else
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Resume sub_exit
End If

End Sub
```

The big thing I did was split off your error handling, this way it only resumes next when you don't find the sheet in wb1 and all other errors (none error 9 errors) will still show your error message.

I also made sure all your Range(), Cells(), and Columns() were referencing the correct sheet (just incase excel is getting confused) and I assumed the active sheet was the correct sheet, but you may want to verify this in the code to make sure it's doing the correct thing in the correct sheet.

Now the copy code only runs if `isWS = true`, and it will always be true unless an error 9 code is thrown. The only thing I didn't know was if wb2 would always have a sheet name equal to `ShtName` but I'm guessing it will since it's inside your if `err.number = 0`

I'm not sure if this will change anything for you, but I'd be curious to hear your results other way.

Comment: I was able to fix it yesterday by removing all `DoEvents` from the code.  I don't know if they were in bad spots or what the issue was but removing them restored everything back to normal.  I did play around quite a bit with that section of code and still had issues even with removing error handling all together.